# Unexpected index phenomenon in R

Tags: indexing

I am reading some mapping from a file. Then, when using this value there appears a strange phenomenon:

```
k <- 66
mapp[k,]
> 66   61    2.345

mapp[k,1] == 66
> TRUE

dat[1,66]
> 5

dat[1, as.numeric(mapp[k,1])]
> 7
```

So, for some strange reason everything points to the fact that mapp[k,1] has the value 66, but when selecting the column of the matrix it is not recognizes as this value!? Why? I tried to read in the mapping with experimenting with the parameter "stringsAsFactors", but it doesn't help.

Anyone any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it was due to R interpreting it as factor, so the value of mapp[k,1] was 364, probably the index of the respective factor.

Problem solved!